# Development and production config on a trigger.io app

Tags: mobile, trigger.io

Our mobile app communicates with a back end API.  We want to be able to query a staged copy of the back end during development, and the live version during production.

We need to be able to dynamically configure our app to query `stage.example.com` during development, and `example.com` during production.

How can I easily manage these configuration parameters using Trigger.io forge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use our [parameters module](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/parameters.html)

This would let you pass a flag into your code at build time which your JavaScript could then use to vary its action e.g.

In config.json:

```
{
    "modules": {
        "parameters": {
             "production": false
        }
    }
}
```

In your JavaScript:

```
if (forge.config.modules.parameters.production) {
    server_url = "example.com";
} else {
    server_url = "staging.example.com";
    forge.enableDebug();
    alert("Set production flag to true before packaging!");
}
```

Comment: How exactly do I set the flag at build time?  Do I need to manually edit config.json depending on what kind of build I want?

Comment: Yes, you would still need to edit config.json to change the flag